# Path Issues - POSIX HFS Cannot get folder

Tags: path, applescript, osascript

I am trying to get this short script to work. All it should do is take the contents of the folder in Application Support/App of the local user and move it to a usb.

```
set localLocation to POSIX path of (path to library folder from user domain) & "Application\\ Support/myApp" as text
set usbLocation to "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp"                                   
tell application "Finder" to move entire contents of folder localLocation to folder usbLocation
```

There is a folder available in both directories (USB & Computer) which match the custom path description described here as "myApp". The code has an error in the first section of the tell, where it is unable to locate the folder in the Application Support. I am not sure why this is the case and I also am struggling to understand the difference between HFS and POSIX, which one is meant to be used? I have a feeling there is a possible concatenate error with types. I am a beginner, please help.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding how AppleScript deals with file and folder references is a headache, and it's very well known to be convoluted and fussy about file specifiers and path strings.

#### Simple definitions:

> **`Posix path:`** A path made up of forward slashes that separate folders in a directory tree, e.g. `/Users/CK/Downloads/Some_File.txt`.
>   The root (top-level) directory is represented by a single forward
>   slash, `/`.  Every posix path is descended from this root directory,
>   so, *generally* speaking, posix paths must start with a forward slash.
>   Folder paths ideally end with a terminating forward slash; file paths
>   do not; but this is not strict.
>
> **`HFS path:`** A path made up of colons that separate folders in a directory tree, e.g. `Macintosh HD:Users:CK:Downloads:Some_File.txt`. 
>   The root directory is represented by `Macintosh HD:`, which always
>   begins an HFS path (unless your system hard drive is called something
>   else).  Folder paths ideally end with a terminating colon; file paths
>   do not; this is semi-strict.

That's literally all you need to know about posix paths and HFS paths to do some AppleScripting.  The tough part is getting to grips with AppleScript's file class types.  There are three:

> **`alias:`** These are your friends, and are the most versatile when used with either *Finder* or *System Events*, and when referring to
>   either files *or* folders.  They are an AppleScript object that
>   contain a file reference that points to **an existing file**.  Trying
>   to assign an `alias` class type to a file reference of a file that
>   does *not* exist will throw an error.
>
> **`file:`** These are a file reference object that may point to a file that doesn't exist (yet).  It qualifies an HFS path string,
>   identifying it as not just a piece of text, but a path to a file.  The
>   key difference between `file` and `alias` is that `file` is a static
>   reference, meaning that if it points to a file with a given name, and
>   that file's name changes, the `file` object will now reference a file
>   that does not exist.  An `alias`, on the other hand, dynamically
>   shifts its reference even after a file is renamed or moved.
>
> **`POSIX file:`** If you like using posix paths (and you should), the `POSIX file` object is your **best** friend.  It takes a posix path
>   string and qualifies it as a path to a file in much the same way
>   `file` does for HFS path strings.  Likewise, it is a static reference
>   and can point to files or folders that don't exist.

#### My recommendation

My feeling is that HFS paths are an unnecessary complication to what could have been an easy inter-formulation between command line users and AppleScripting.  They do confuse people, and since the notation is so widely observed through the results returned by an AppleScript, they appear mandatory in their use.

They are not.  I, personally, **never** use HFS paths. (Almost never).

One isn't intrinsically better than the other, and it is really just a personal preference.  So my advice is to pick one style that you're most comfortable with, and learn how to manipulate that type of path in the AppleScript setting.

As I use posix paths, I concern myself with `POSIX file` objects, and `alias` objects.  That's what I'll focus on now for the rest of this answer.

### Your script

Your script threw its first error because you attempted to escape the spaces within the file path string, possibly a habit from typing in a terminal.  You **don't** need to escape **any** characters in a file string, except for the backslash `\`, as file path strings will always be enclosed within double quotes.

Still addressing the first line of your script, you have quite correctly retrieved the `path to` the `library folder` (which returns an *`alias`*); turned it into a posix path string; then appended the `"Application Support/myApp"` path text.  However, it may be helpful to know that you can actually get the `path to` the `application support` folder, so your first line can become:

```
set localLocation to POSIX path of (path to application support from user domain) & "myApp"
```

The result is a posix path **string**, but not a file object (but that's fine at the moment).

Your next line then explicitly declares a posix path string:

```
set usbLocation to "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp"
```

which is absolutely fine.

The bit that comes next is the tricky stuff: working with *Finder*:

```
tell application "Finder" to move entire contents of ¬
    folder localLocation to folder usbLocation
```

That said, you had it *almost* perfect.  Because you're using posix paths, you either need to turn them into `alias` objects, or explain to finder that it's dealing with a posix path, which is what the `POSIX file` object does.

To create a `POSIX file` object, you can either prepend the `POSIX file` specifier to the posix path string like this:

```
set usbLocation to POSIX file "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp"
```

or do a more conventional coercion into a type class like this:

```
set usbLocation to "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp" as POSIX file
```

In either case, AppleScript turns this into a `file` object and converts it to an HFS path.  If you run that line just above by itself, AppleScript returns this:

```
file "Macintosh HD:Volumes:myUsb:myApp"
```

So, already, we can see there's an equivalence between `file` objects and HFS paths versus `POSIX file` objects and posix paths.

You can choose to edit lines 1 and 2 of your script to construct these `POSIX file` objects straight away; or you can do it at the point where you are interacting with *Finder*:

```
tell application "Finder" to move entire contents of ¬
    folder (localLocation as POSIX file) to folder (usbLocation as POSIX file)
```

If doing it here, you have to coerce using **`as`**, possibly because prepending it as an object specifier interferes with `folder` in the role of an object specifier.

That should successfully move all the files into their new location.  The other way you could do it is by moving the folder instead of its contents, which is probably quicker if there are many files and sub-directories.  Just change the destination path accordingly:

```
set localLocation to POSIX path of (path to application support folder from user domain) & "myApp" as POSIX file
set usbLocation to POSIX file "/Volumes/myUsb/"

tell application "Finder" to move folder localLocation to folder usbLocation with replacing
```

(the `with replacing` is because the folder `myApp` in the destination will be getting replaced by the folder `myApp` coming from your hard drive.)

Finally, for completeness, I'll briefly talk about `alias` objects:

#### Alias objects

Constructing `alias` objects from posix paths is fairly simple, and requires two steps.  Firstly, you construct the `POSIX file` object as I showed you above.  Then, you coerce this object into an `alias`.  It can be done on one line:

```
set usbLocation to POSIX file "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp" as alias
```

or

```
set usbLocation to "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp" as POSIX file as alias
```

Remember, however, that `alias` objects point to files and folders that already exist.  Therefore, there will be some instances where you can declare your `POSIX file` object immediately from a posix path string that points to a non-existent file that, for example, you will be creating.  But you can only coerce it into an `alias` after the file has been created.

One reason you might want to use `alias` objects is because they are dynamic, as I mentioned before (or, they *should* be).  So if you set `localLocation` as an `alias` object at the start, then moved the folder to its destination as in my very last *Finder* example, the `alias object` should now automatically point to `/Volumes/myUsb/myApp/` (although it doesn't always work successfully, as one of the many bugs AppleScript has).

The other, more important, reason to use `alias` objects is that they translate directly between the different applications AppleScript interacts with: not all utilise `POSIX file` objects, and some may not utilise HFS paths; but they virtually all know what an `alias` object is.

This is key when switching between *Finder* and *System Events* for file handling.  Generally speaking, file and folder handling is best done with *System Events* rather than *Finder*.  But, there are a couple of things you can only do in *Finder*: set a file tag (`label index`); get the selected files (`selection`); and know which target folder has focus at the present time (`insertion location`).

Retrieving the `selection` in *Finder* returns *Finder*-specific classes, namely `document files`.  One cannot utilise these objects with *System Events*.  However, the `selection as alias list` is something that can be manipulated by *System Events*:

```
tell application "Finder" to set S to selection as alias list

tell application "System Events" to get properties of item 1 of S
```

Finally, the third reason to utilise `alias` objects is because, for some reason, retrieving files as `alias` objects is noticeably faster than retrieving them as any other class object.  Testing this on the contents of my downloads folder (which is small enough to not keep me waiting, but large enough to get *Finder* working), the results were:

```
tell application "Finder" to get entire contents of ¬
    (path to downloads folder) as alias list
-- 1.45s

tell application "Finder" to get entire contents of ¬
    (path to downloads folder)
-- 2.29s
```

They are identical statements, with the exception of the coercion to an `alias list` (a list of `alias` file objects) in the first.  The speed benefit will be more noticeable on larger folders.

Utilising `alias` objects with *Finder* is a little easier/simpler than with `file` or `POSIX file` objects, because `alias` objects don't make a distinction between files and folders in the way that the other two do.  In your script, it's necessary with *Finder* to use the `folder` specifier with the `POSIX file` objects; with an `alias` object, you don't need to:

```
set localLocation to POSIX path of (path to application support folder from user domain) & "myApp" as POSIX file as alias
set usbLocation to POSIX file "/Volumes/myUsb/" as alias

tell application "Finder" to move localLocation to usbLocation with replacing
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using debugging print statements (display dialog) and noticed the paths were being converted to HFS. This didn't make any sense to me, as I am much more familiar and comfortable with POSIX, why didn't applescript just use the POSIX I gave. I hadn't seen HFS until I began trying to create this basic script.

That speed difference in retrieving files is incredibly significant, I will be sure to use that in future! 

Thank you, for your incredibly logical, succinct but detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree to be discouraged from using HFS paths.

If you have to use the Finder it's the most convenient way since the Finder doesn't accept POSIX paths.

To address a folder on the top level of an external volume there is another short way in Finder terminology : `folder "foo" of disk "bar"`.

```
set localLocation to (path to application support folder from user domain as text) & "myApp"                                  
tell application "Finder" to move entire contents of folder localLocation to folder "myApp" of disk "myUsb"
```

However `entire contents` in Finder can be extremely slow. The shell is much faster.

```
set localLocation to POSIX path of (path to application support folder from user domain) & "myApp/" 
set usbLocation to "/Volumes/myUsb/myApp"                                    
do shell script "/bin/cp " & quoted form of localLocation & "*" & space & quoted form of usbLocation
```

Comment: It is incredibly confusing that Finder doesn't accept POSIX paths. That address of external volume is also very simple.

I also didn't know "do shell script "/bin/cp"" was a possibility. If I required to move the files instead of copying them, would "do shell "/bin/mv"" work equally well? I am much more familiar with terminal commands than Applescript and I was curious how I would be able to integrate those commands. Thank you very much for your sharing your supportive view to HFS paths, greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/bin/cp` is just the equivalent to Finder's `move` which does *copy* the files if the destination is on a different volume. You can use all shell commands as an argument of `do shell script`.

Comment: I agree 100% - the shell is far more efficient than `entire contents` - particularly given OP's requirement.  If intention is to regularly copy folder contents from  local user to USB drive, (perhaps for regular backup purposes), then consider utilizing [`rsync`](https://ss64.com/osx/rsync.html) instead of [`cp`](https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html) for further efficiency. For instance: `do shell script "rsync -a " & quoted form of localLocation & space & quoted form of usbLocation`

Comment: Note: Appending the asterisk `*` wildcard, (i.e. `& "*"` to the `localLocation` path), in the `do shell script` command didn't work for me when using `cp`. I used the `-R` (recursive) option instead: For instance: `do shell script "/bin/cp -R " & quoted form of localLocation & space & quoted form of usbLocation`